# JetBrains Mono is not available in Android Studio

Tags: windows, android-studio, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-font

I don't know why, I can't choose JetBrains Mono as my editor font in Android Studio 4.1 on Windows. The font is not available in the dropdown menu.
I have other IDE (IntelliJ) on the same machine on which JetBrains Mono was enabled by default and "just works".

Do you have any clue about that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and the following works for me.

1. Download font from https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mono/
2. Install it as OS X system font
3. Restart Android Studio
4. 'JetBrains Mono' is appeared in the Android Studion > Preference > Editor > Font